# Angular multiple website and block import

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an angular project which contains two areas (1 website, 2 admin)

This project has a structure:

- /src/website/*
- /src/admin/*

This project has separate services but they have the same name

- /src/website/news/news.service.ts
- /src/admin/news/news.service.ts

Now, for example, I created a new component in the admin area and I want to use only components/services which contain in /src/admin/*

But now, when I need to use NewsService in the new component, I get popup helper (which contains two options: `import /src/website/news/news.service.ts`

or

`import /src/admin/news/news.service.ts)`,

but I want to get only one option  (`import /src/admin/news/news.service.ts`).

How can I configure VisualCode/Typescript, then I can get that result?

Comment: If you continue to give services the same name, this will happen. This isn't a problem with the tools you are using. The application design isn't ideal.

Comment: @R.Richards what do you recommend then?

Comment: Change the name of your services to be unique.